# Python - adding conditions in if only they are specified (domain)?

Tags: python

I'm writing a method that will filter records by called conditions. What I mean, is it will check if default conditions are met for any record and then if specified, checks if additional conditions needs to be met for those records. But if those conditions are not specified, it will just ignore it.

So I could write it like this:

```
def test_conditions(a, b=None)
    #b - this one is additional condition that might be specified or not
    if a > 5 and (b > 10 if b else True):
        print 'record passed'
```

It is working I need to, but I don't think it looks very elegant and I will need to use more than one additional condition that might or might not be specified when method is called and then such method might not look good.

So maybe there is some practice in Python how to best solve such problems (I mean best way to handle those additional conditions when you don't know if you will need to check it or not before method is called)?

I was asked to provide real code I was writing, so here it is:

```
def countEmergency(self, card_ids, duration=None):
    cnt = 0
    for card in card_ids:
        if card.emergency_level == 'first' and (card.duration > duration if duration else True):
            cnt += 1
    return cnt
```

Comment: @GreenAsJade no, it wont always print 'record passed'. If you specify b lower than 10, it wont pass. And yeah, that is just a typo, it does not matter it value. I just wanted to clarify what I mean default condition and additional. But I can add it in method call to look more meaningful. Also I can post real code, but its really just about how to handle such cases in python.

Comment: Actually it will *never* `print 'record passed'` (`a > 5` always evaluates` False`). A less abstract example would probably be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that. I will edit it

Comment: For the specific real-code case posted, it looks OK to me: I'm not sure I'd try to do that differently.   It reads very clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than `print` I would `return` either `True` or `False`, then you can check each item individually. Assuming that you're testing the attributes on some object (but this can be adapted to whatever you need):

```
def test_conditions(obj, a=5, b=None):
    if obj.a <= a:
        return False
    if b is not None and obj.b <= b:
        return False
    return True
```

Alternatively, use `**kwargs` to take arbitrary keyword arguments:

```
def test_conditions(obj, a=5, **kwargs):
    if obj.a <= a:
        return False
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        if getattr(obj, k) <= v:
            return False
    return True
```

or

```
def test_conditions(obj, **kwargs):
    if obj.a <= kwargs.get('a', 5):
        return False
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        if getattr(obj, k) <= v:
            return False
    return True
```

---

Given what you're *actually* doing, use `continue` instead of returning:

```
def countEmergency(self, card_ids, duration=None):
    cnt = 0
    for card in card_ids:
        if card.emergency_level != 'first':
            continue
        if duration is not None and card.duration <= duration:
            continue
        cnt += 1
    return cnt
```

Alternatively, refactor to use a function as above, that takes one `card`, and use `filter` to get a list of valid elements from `card_ids`.

```
from functools import partial

class WhateverThisIs(object):

    ...

    @staticmethod
    def validate_card(card, duration=None):
        if card.emergency_level != 'first':
            return False
        if duration is not None and card.duration <= duration:
            return False
        return True

    def countEmergency(self, card_ids, duration=None):
        return len(filter(partial(self.validate_card, duration=duration), card_ids))
```

This uses [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to create an appropriate filtering function. Note that your `countEmergency` doesn't use any instance or class attributes or methods - you should review whether it needs to be an instance method.

Comment: I'm actually doing the counting of those records. So would need to get total count of passed records.

Comment: @Andrius `len(filter(test_conditions, records))` (or use `functools.partial` for e.g. `len(filter(partial(test_conditions, b=10), records))`)? If you needed the count, why on earth did you `print`?

Comment: Well that was just to output anything, I was just asking how to handle conditions. But I posted what I was actually doing and updated my question for better understanding of the problem.

Comment: @Andrius this is why it's helpful to provide a snippet that *actually represents what you're doing*. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, this looks that might be a good solution to use continue. Just one suggestion. I think `if duration..` instead of `if duration is not None..` is more elegant.

Comment: @Andrius what about `duration=0`? You should always check for singletons like `None` by identity, using `is`. See [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations).

Comment: Yeah in that case I agree. Just In my case if `0` would be provided it would mean same as None (in my context), because it should not check if duration is higher (or lower) than `0`.

Comment: @Andrius checking `duration <= 0` is *not* necessarily the same as not checking, and should not be treated as such. Be consistent and test `None` with `is`; it will help you avoid other subtle edge cases.